# Excerpt displays � instead of ÆØÅ

Tags: wordpress, encoding

Probably becourse it read it as

æ as & aelig;

ø as & oslash;

å as & aring;

http://img.lajlev.dk/ef75fcacb8ac88abb3aa93fd904335d2.png

How do I make wordpress display æøå and not cut it of like &osl which results in �

Comment: This is gibberish - please edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are using UTF-8 (if you view the source code, you see &osl or the same � that appears in the html output? If it's the latter, then you are using utf-8 (which btw is what I always recommend, so not bad at all).

The problem with utf-8 is that it is a multibyte encoding which means that some letters use more than 1 byte. PHP functions dealing with strings, such as `substr()` (which is the functions that gets a piece of a bigger string, in this case, the excerpt of the full article text), think that 1 character = 1 byte, so substr works at byte level, not character level.

I don't know wordpress nor how the excerpt mechanism works, so I won't tell you any solution (I have a few ideas, but may not be the best, and if you don't know PHP then they will only confuse you).

Check google for `wordpress excerpt utf-8 substr` or some variation of it.